# Java I/O using inpout32.dll

Tags: java, dll, io, java-native-interface, native

I am trying to control some LEDs wired to the parallel port on Windows XP. The easiest solution would be [Inpout32.dll](http://logix4u.net/Legacy_Ports/Parallel_Port/Inpout32.dll_for_Windows_98/2000/NT/XP.html) from [Logix4u.net](http://logix4u.net/). I have found many source code samples in various languages (C++, Visual Basic, C#) but nothing using Java.

Do you know any tutorials about calling DLL functions from Java ? (what I have found so far on Google are not so advanced).

Environment: Java 1.6.0, Windows XP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic way to access native code from Java is [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

However, there are frameworks like [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) and/or [JInvoke](http://www.jinvoke.com) hiding all complexity of JNI and providing interface similar to VBasic and C#.

BTW, there are JNI library and samples for your specific DLL [here](http://www.hytherion.com/beattidp/comput/pport.htm)

Answer (score 2):

There is also [JNIWrapper](http://www.teamdev.com/jniwrapper/index.jsf)